# how can fix Static Injector Error in angular 6?

Tags: angular

i have this error on angular. how can fix it. thank for taking your time.

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UnitPriceComponent -> Subscription]: 
 StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[UnitPriceComponent -> Subscription]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for Subscription!
at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1060)
at resolveToken (core.js:1298)
at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1139)
at resolveToken (core.js:1298)
at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1139)
at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8374)
at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:9062)
at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8374)
```

Comment: what is Subscription? if it's service you should add it to your providers array of appModule.

Comment: all services that use are in providers of appModule.

Comment: ```import { Subscription } from "rxjs";``` angular 6.

Comment: Remove Subscription  from constructor